# How to use multiple js using Webpack.mix.js in Laravel 7?

Tags: jquery, node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-7

I my project I am using **Bootstrap.js**, **Jquery.js** , **Jquery_validation.js** and one **custom.js**(for project specific rules).

I want to use only one app.js on all pages. what is the best way to use webpack.mix ?

I have installed jquery and jquery-validation , Please suggest me.

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": {
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.1",
    "savvy-js": "^1.0.7"
}
```

in resource/js/app.js

```
require('jquery-validation');

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

webpack.mix

```
mix.js(['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/snavvy.js'], 'public/js')
```

.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });

So Please tell me how to use bootstrap.js, jquery.js, jquery-validation.js and custom.js(resource/js/custom.js) in best way ?

Comment: This is a pretty standard laravel setup.  In your `app.blade.php`, you should have `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` which includes the script you've created.

Comment: Yes, I am using it but I have multiple js (bootstrap,jquery,jquery_validation & one custom js) so need to combine them.

Comment: Have you run "npm run production" yet?

Answer (score 2):

The **webpack.mix.js** need the file extensions; the folder is not enough. I usually link the *.sass* to my view. Something like

```
//does not work
mix.js(['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/snavvy.js'], 'public/js');


//sucessful
mix.js('resources/js/app.js','public/js');

//or if you want a custom name
mix.js('resources/js/snavvy.js', 'public/js/custom_snavvy.js');
```

```
npm run dev

//or

npm run watch
```

Good luck.

Comment: I added file name with extention. mix.js(['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/snavvy.js'], 'public/js/app.js'), but still snavvy is not working.

Comment: try take out '['  and ']' and put the .js views at separated mix.js class.

Comment: i'ts exactly as "//sucessful" it

Comment: new editied answer creating two js files in public/js folder then what is advantage of webpack.mix .

Comment: compile the files to a certain directory with their appropriate libraries. This is just an syntax issue

Comment: The main libraries are in node_modules that it's not safe to be available to the user

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
mix.js([
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
    'resources/plugins/bootstrap-3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js',
     ...
], 'public/js/app.js').version();
```

[Further Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622118/combining-multiple-files-with-laravel-mix)